# Firebase Passing State(continue to app link) in Password Reset Email

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

Trying to build a password reset flow where the user receives password reset email, reset's their password and then is guided back to the app. trying to avoid deep linking, just need to open the app back up.

The app is using latest Ionic and Angular version with Firebase authentication.

**Problem**: I am able to send the password reset email and change the password for that account but when I click the continue button provided by the firebase, it breaks on Android and iPhone. The link also starts with localhost. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or if I have configured something incorrectly.

Also confused by Firebase's documentation when it says, "The Android/iOS app needs to be registered in the Console."

Really have ran out of ideas!

My action code settings are pretty much default.

The url is whitelisted in Firebase's authorized domains.

```
var actionCodeSettings = {
 url: 'https://www.myapp.com/?email=' + email,
 iOS: {
  bundleId: 'com.myapp.new'
 },
 android: {
  packageName: 'com.myapp.new',
  installApp: true,
  minimumVersion: '2'
 },
 handleCodeInApp: false
};
```

Here is what the link looks like

```
https://localhost/?link=https://myapp.com/?email%3Demail@example.com&apn=com.myapp.new&amv=2&ibi=com.myapp.new&ifl=https://myapp.com/?email%3Demail@example.com
```

Comment: Where you test this? On `device` or `browser`?

Comment: device, build ios and running through xcode and android straight from the ionic command line

Comment: Did you follow any article? URL?

Comment: yup, been following the docs, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your FDL domain is not configured. It is being replaced by `localhost`, strangely. An error should be returned in that case. Can you go to dynamic links section and agree to the terms of FDL? The domain should look something like `example.app.goo.gl`.

Comment: You were right, the actual dynamic links weren't configured properly!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend reading [**this article**](https://javebratt.com/ionic-firebase-authentication/) to see how to do it properly with Ionic. If that is not what you need please let me know.

*.ts*

```
resetPassword(){
  if (!this.resetPasswordForm.valid){
    console.log(this.resetPasswordForm.value);
  } else {
    this.authProvider.resetPassword(this.resetPasswordForm.value.email)
    .then((user) => {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        message: "We just sent you a reset link to your email",
        buttons: [
          {
            text: "Ok",
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => { this.navCtrl.pop(); }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();

    }, (error) => {
      var errorMessage: string = error.message;
      let errorAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        message: errorMessage,
        buttons: [{ text: "Ok", role: 'cancel' }]
      });
      errorAlert.present();
    });
  }
}
```